# Error in javascript file but not console?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, spservices

The error in question

```
Uncaught Error: The property or field has not been initialized. 
It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. 
It may need to be explicitly requested.
```

Here is the code, just trying to get a simple count of a list.

```
var CustomAction = function(){

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web(); 
    this.oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Classification");

    // .load() tells CSOM to load the properties of this object
    // multiple .load()s can be stacked
    clientContext.load(oList);

    // now start the asynchronous call and perform all commands
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailure));

    // method will exit here and onSuccess or OnFail will be called asynchronously

};

function onSuccess(sender, args) {
    alert('No of rows: ' + oList.get_itemCount());
};

function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed.\n' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
};
```

The error occurs at  `oList.get_itemCount()`. What reason would there be for this to be happening? I tried using `$( document).ready` and `$(window).onload` but the problem still occurs. So like I said, it works when I copy/paste that into the browser but running it from file it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```js
var CustomAction = function(){

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web(); 
    this.oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Classification");

    // .load() tells CSOM to load the properties of this object
    // multiple .load()s can be stacked
    clientContext.load(oList);

    // now start the asynchronous call and perform all commands

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync((function(sender, args){alert('No of rows: ' + oList.get_itemCount())}(this, this.onSuccess)), (function(sender, args){alert('Request failed.\n' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace())}(this, this.onFailure)));
};
```

Comment: That causes `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'propertyHasNotBeenInitialized' of undefined` but running in the console also causes the original error instead of this one.

Comment: hmmm... are you wrapping your function with `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` by the way?

Comment: I am, `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomAction, "sp.js")` Is it maybe because I have to say the directory of the file or does that not matter.

Comment: Oh the file is in a folder? That I'm not sure. I would suggest testing on a different list/library. I would also suggest asking this question  in [SharePoint StackExchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Sorry, what I said didn't make much sense. I meant that "sp.js" might not be pointing correctly but it does not seem to care about that so that's irrelevant. I have posted there though so thank you!